# What is the best way to present the repetitive task of a "user filling out a doctor schedule" 3 to 5 times?

Tags: forms

This task needs to be done by an admin to create a doctor schedule and fill the working hours and shifts for the doctor each week. I am facing the issue of how to present each week's schedule in a good user experience view?

In the given scenario the image shows a scheduling period of one month and shows one week only. How can I show the other three weeks and decrease the repetitive task to fill each week?

[image: scheduling plan]

Answer (score 1):

I'd make it a standard calendar such as Google calendar so that people are already familiar with the pattern and I imagine entry will be a lot faster, could test that.

Add buttons to copy and paste a week's schedule for easy duplication.

Also, consider how the schedule is decided. For example I know that veterinarians (similar situation I imagine) share a spreadsheet amongst the team that goes back and forth to decide who works when. If that is the case for you as well, consider a spreadsheet import function to add multiple doctors schedules at once.

Answer (score 0):

You could use tabs or collapsers to separate the weeks. I would also add a button to copy the working hours from one week to the other.

Answer (score 0):

One quick win could be to set the time for all (work)days and then only have to alter the deviation. Same for following weeks (the assumption is that most weeks are similar)